# autofac baseclass property is null

Tags: autofac

Here is my setup with Asp.Net Mvc 3:

```
public abstract class BaseProvider
{
    protected ICache Cache;
}

public interface ICache
{
    void Add(string key, object data);
    void Remove(string key);
    ...
}

public class MyCache : ICache
{
    private static MemoryCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
    void Add(string key, object data)
    {
    ...
    }
}

public interface IEmployeeProvider
{
    IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployees(string department);
}

public class EmployeeProvider:BaseProvider,IEmployeeProvider
{
    public IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployees(string department)
    {
         **if (Cache.Get("employees_"+department)!=null)**

    }
}
```

Starred line throws an error saying that Cache is null.
I tried to register the base class as a type but, I guess it is wrong.
My Autofac setup is like this:

```
builder.Register(r => new EmployeeProvider()).As<IEmployeeProvider>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
builder.Register(r => new MyCache()).As<ICache>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
builder.RegisterType<BaseProvider>().PropertiesAutowired();
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You should either register `EmployeeProvider` with `PropertiesAutowired()` or scan the assembly for every class that inherits from `BaseProvider`.

The first registration forgets the `PropertiesAutowired()`, the third line forgets the `EmployeeProvider`.